# when i tried to run below coding i got an error, so guys try to solve the error

Tags: python, image, opencv, processing

```
filepath = 'blackmeasles (1).jpg'

BLUR = 21
CANNY_THRESH_1 = 10
CANNY_THRESH_2 = 200
MASK_DILATE_ITER = 10
MASK_ERODE_ITER = 10
MASK_COLOR = (0.0,0.0,0.0) # In BGR format

img = cv2.imread(filepath)
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

edges = cv2.Canny(gray, CANNY_THRESH_1, CANNY_THRESH_2)
edges = cv2.dilate(edges, None)
edges = cv2.erode(edges, None)

contour_info = []
_, contours = cv2.findContours(edges, cv2.RETR_LIST, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)

for c in contours:
    contour_info.append((c, cv2.isContourConvex(c), cv2.contourArea(c),))
contour_info = sorted(contour_info, key=lambda c: c[2], reverse=True)

max_contour = contour_info[0]
mask = np.zeros(edges.shape)
cv2.fillConvexPoly(mask, max_contour[0], (255))

mask = cv2.dilate(mask, None, iterations=MASK_DILATE_ITER)
mask = cv2.erode(mask, None, iterations=MASK_ERODE_ITER)
mask = cv2.GaussianBlur(mask, (BLUR, BLUR), 0)

mask_stack = np.dstack([mask]*3)
mask_stack  = mask_stack.astype('float32') / 255.0
img = img.astype('float32') / 255.0

masked = (mask_stack * img) + ((1-mask_stack) * MASK_COLOR)
masked = (masked * 255).astype('uint8')

fileName, fileExtension = filepath.split('.')
fileName += '-masked.'
filepath = fileName + fileExtension
print(filepath)

cv2.imwrite(filepath, masked)
```

I got the below error, Guys help me to solve,

> image classification domain
> ---> 21             contour_info.append((c, cv2.isContourConvex(c), cv2.contourArea(c),))
> 22         contour_info = sorted(contour_info, key=lambda c: c[2], reverse=True)
> 23
>
> error: OpenCV(4.5.4-dev) D:\a\opencv-python\opencv-python\opencv\modules\imgproc\src\convhull.cpp:447: error: (-215:Assertion failed) total >= 0 && (depth == CV_32F || depth == CV_32S) in function 'cv::isContourConvex'

Comment: The call to `cv2.isContourConvex(c)` is the problem - are the contours closed? What requirements do they have to meet for `isContourConvex` to be able to process them?

Comment: before wondering, just *print* and look at the contour that triggers the exception

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Thank you very much to all (Grismar, Christoph Rackwitz), I debugged and got it !

Answer (score 0):

Let me make a suggestion that may help you to figure out your problem.

```
error: (-215:Assertion failed) total >= 0 && (depth == CV_32F || depth == CV_32S) in function 'cv::isContourConvex'
```

This erorr means you should check the actual `cv::isCounterConvex()` function to see why the `total` is not greater than 0 and the depth parameter is not either equal to `CV_32F` or `CV_32S`. Then you will probably solve your problem.
These assertions are the best type of errors because it actually says the problem, the only thing you should do is to read it carefully and check the source to see what's really going on.

Comment: not *why are they* but **why aren't they**. the assertion, which is that expression, *failed*

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, now i can understand the assertion given, finally i got it.

Comment: Happy to hear that! :)